# React-rails install error Webpacker configuration file not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

After upgrade rails 3 to rails 4.2.4, i want to use react-rails gem in my project.i follow official react-rails document.

`rake webpacker:install` getting this error.

```
Webpacker configuration file not found /home/projects/config/webpacker.yml. Please run rails webpacker:install Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/projects/config/webpacker.yml
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/webpacker-3.5.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:73:in `rescue in load'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/webpacker-3.5.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:70:in `load'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/webpacker-3.5.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:66:in `data'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/webpacker-3.5.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:62:in `fetch'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/webpacker-3.5.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:17:in `compile?'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/webpacker-3.5.2/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:32:in `compiling?'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/webpacker-3.5.2/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:22:in `lookup'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/react-rails-2.4.4/lib/react/server_rendering/webpacker_manifest_container.rb:42:in `find_asset'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/react-rails-2.4.4/lib/react/server_rendering/bundle_renderer.rb:27:in `block in initialize'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/react-rails-2.4.4/lib/react/server_rendering/bundle_renderer.rb:26:in `each'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/react-rails-2.4.4/lib/react/server_rendering/bundle_renderer.rb:26:in `initialize'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/react-rails-2.4.4/lib/react/server_rendering.rb:17:in `new'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/react-rails-2.4.4/lib/react/server_rendering.rb:17:in `block in reset_pool'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/connection_pool-0.9.3/lib/timed_queue.rb:6:in `block in initialize'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/connection_pool-0.9.3/lib/timed_queue.rb:6:in `initialize'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/connection_pool-0.9.3/lib/timed_queue.rb:6:in `new'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/connection_pool-0.9.3/lib/timed_queue.rb:6:in `initialize'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/connection_pool-0.9.3/lib/connection_pool.rb:42:in `new'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/connection_pool-0.9.3/lib/connection_pool.rb:42:in `initialize'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/react-rails-2.4.4/lib/react/server_rendering.rb:17:in `new'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/react-rails-2.4.4/lib/react/server_rendering.rb:17:in `reset_pool'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/react-rails-2.4.4/lib/react/rails/railtie.rb:104:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
/home/projects/config/environment.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
```

please help me, i created new demo app with rails 4.2.4 it working fine, but not my existing app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Webpacker for React on an existing Rails 5.0.2 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48999511/how-to-use-webpacker-for-react-on-an-existing-rails-5-0-2-application)

Comment: i am using rails 4.2 ...

Comment: "The apparent solution is to copy the config/webpacker.yml file manually"

Comment: i already manually added wepbacker.yml into configuration, after it show above error. then i copy webpacke folder into config  and webpacker and runner into bin fine after that i run rake webpacker:install:react.  it show error

Comment: [Webpacker] Compilation failed:
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

Answer (score 6):

Take this file into the folder /Users/YourAPP/config https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/lib/install/config/webpacker.yml

Answer (score 2):

This is 3 step process:

- Step 1 :  Create a webpacker.yml into the config folder so path will be 
            config/webpacker.yml
- Step 2 :  paste below content into the webpacker.yml file.

```
    default: &default
      source_path: app/javascript
      source_entry_path: packs
      public_root_path: public
      public_output_path: packs
      cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
      check_yarn_integrity: false
      webpack_compile_output: false

      resolved_paths: []
      cache_manifest: false
      extract_css: false

      static_assets_extensions:
        - .jpg
        - .jpeg
        - .png
        - .gif
        - .tiff
        - .ico
        - .svg
        - .eot
        - .otf
        - .ttf
        - .woff
        - .woff2

      extensions:
        - .mjs
        - .js
        - .sass
        - .scss
        - .css
        - .module.sass
        - .module.scss
        - .module.css
        - .png
        - .svg
        - .gif
        - .jpeg
        - .jpg

    development:
      <<: *default
      compile: true

      check_yarn_integrity: true

      dev_server:
        https: false
        host: localhost
        port: 3035
        public: localhost:3035
        hmr: false
        inline: true
        overlay: true
        compress: true
        disable_host_check: true
        use_local_ip: false
        quiet: false
        pretty: false
        headers:
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        watch_options:
          ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


    test:
      <<: *default
      compile: true

      # Compile test packs to a separate directory
      public_output_path: packs-test

    production:
      <<: *default

      # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
      compile: false

      # Extract and emit a css file
      extract_css: true

      # Cache manifest.json for perfo`enter code here`rmance
      cache_manifest: true
```

- Step 3: restart the server

Comment: I have the same issue. I have no webpacker.yml file. Upon trying this the rails gives me this error in the command line ```YAML syntax error occurred while parsing Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 1 column 2 (RuntimeError)```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the files, maybe you have not Yarn installed 
https://yarnpkg.com/lang/fr/docs/install/#mac-stable